# 2D array using pointers - Memory leakage

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

```
double* sol = (double*) calloc(n_samp, sizeof(double));
double** m = (double**) calloc(n_samp, sizeof(double*));
for (int i = 0; i < n_samp; i++){
    *(m+i) = (double*) calloc((n_samp + 1), sizeof(double));
}
```

I am generating a 2D array using the above. It works fine but valgrind is telling me that there's a memory leak. What is the proper way to free the memories here?

Comment: You should not cast the return values of `calloc` in C

Comment: Just do the reverse of allocating the memory

Comment: @EdHeal Thanks for the comment. Sorry I'm not sure what you mean exactly. So should I just do free(sol), free(m), and for loop{free((m+i))}?

Comment: Run the loop to free that memory, then free `m` and `sol`

Comment: @EdHeal If what I stated above is correct, then I really have no idea why there's still a memory leak.

Comment: Do it in reverse. Loop first,` m` then `sol`

Comment: @EdHeal That is what I have done so far. Hmm..

Comment: you are doing the loop after free `m`. wrong way around

Comment: Where is the 2D array?

Comment: To support @MartinJames: There is no 2D array in your code. Pointers and arrays are different types and cannot be interchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To free the memory, you have to do the exact opposite of what you did when allocating the memory.

Start with the dynamic elements which you have created insid the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n_samp; i++){
    free( *(m+i) );
}
```

and then do the rest:

```
free( m );
free( sol );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately that's what I have done (the comment I left above was wrong sorry).

Comment: Yes. Valgrind is still giving me an error message for 'calloc'.

Comment: @DavidYoung If you think you've already done this and it still doesn't work, then you need to post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Rabbit76 You mean between calloc and free, I don't think so, it's a const.

Comment: @Rabbit76 wow, I just realized that I only free the memories after I return the function output. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Actually, why can't you free() after returning the function output?